# Information Diffusion

Tags: network-programming, netlogo, information-visualization

I've got a problem with netlogo: I want to spread an information in a network. One turtle has the information and gives it to its link-neighbors with a constant probability. This is the code i have so far:

```
to spread
  if (count turtles with [informed? = true] > .7 * count turtles) [stop]
  ask turtles with [ informed? = true ]
  [
      ask link-neighbors
      [
        if (random-float 1 <= 0.02)
          [
            set informed? true
             show-turtle
            set color green
          ]
        ]
      ]

  set num-informed count turtles with [informed? = true]
  tick
end
```

Now I want to know: How can I ensure, that every turtle gets the information only ONCE and is not informed twice? I tried "if not informed?", but that only got me error messages. And did I get the command "if (random-float 1 <= 0.02)" right, if i want the information to be spread with a constant probability of 2%?

Comment: yes, the random-float is used properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (not tested). Assumes that you have done `set informed? FALSE` when you set up the turtles.

```
to spread
  if (count turtles with [informed?] > .7 * count turtles) [stop]
  ask turtles with [ informed? ]
  [ ask link-neighbors with [ not informed? ] ; **<= my change**
    [ if (random-float 1 <= 0.02)
      [ set informed? true
        show-turtle
        set color green
      ]
    ]
  ]

  set num-informed count turtles with [informed?]
  tick
end
```

Comment: when a variable X? is boolean (only TRUE or FALSE), you don't actually need to say `X? = TRUE`, can simply say `X?` and similarly `not X?` for `X? = FALSE`

Comment: I guess I did not fix his?

Comment: well there is no error message anymore and I think it works so far... thank you so much for the fast answers!

Comment: @King-Ink You did fix this. But you originally wrote that you would come back after dinner to write it out better. I just did the clean up for you. You can see what anyone did by following the link 'edited ....' above my name